# How to generate an unnested array in BigQuery using existing timestamp

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery

I'd like to take this query (which works for me):

```
SELECT(DATE_ADD(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL 1* n MONTH)) as date
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,12,1)) n
```

And replace the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` with a `start_date` timestamp field from an existing table.

In other words, I'd like to create a list of "active months" for a contract that begins on `start_date`.

I'm getting stuck on how to incorporate another `FROM` clause!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT(DATE_ADD(DATE(start_date), INTERVAL 1* n MONTH)) as date
FROM ExistingTable, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,12,1)) n
```

If you have exactly one row in the existing table representing the start date, you can use a subselect:

```
SELECT(DATE_ADD(DATE((SELECT start_date FROM ExistingTable)), INTERVAL 1* n MONTH)) as date
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,12,1)) n
```